# Location of spelling dictionary in TeXShop on El Capitan

Tags: texshop, mac, spelling, dictionaries

I was doing a spell check in TeXShop 3.58 and accidentally clicked on "Learn" for a word that isn't a word ("subalfgebra", in case you're wondering).  I'd like to fix this by editing the dictionary manually but cannot figure out where TeXShop keeps its word list.  The fake word does not appear in ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary, for example.  I have not installed any additional spell checker such as Cocoaspell or Excalibur.

Comment: Does the misspelt word now show up as correctly spelled in both TeXShop and other Mac apps (e.g. Mail?).

Comment: Yes, it did.  Actually, I figured how to fix the problem - it wasn't TeXShop's fault.  I just had to restart AppleSpell.  For reference, here's what you do:

 (1) remove the fake word from ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary

 (2) quit TeXShop

 (3) open up a Terminal window and type "killall AppleSpell"

 (4) restart TexShop.

For details: [https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6844365?start=0&tstart=0].  Thanks for asking the question that led to the solution

Comment: I'm glad you got things sorted. Since this is something that others might encounter you should turn your comment into an answer. It's perfectly fine to answer (and accept) your own question. You can answer right away but I think you need to wait two days before accepting a self answer.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered how to fix the problem.  Restart AppleSpell, as follows:

1. Remove the fake word from `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`.
2. Quit TeXShop (and any other apps that are using AppleSpell).
3. Open a Terminal window and type `killall AppleSpell`
4. Restart TexShop.

See also: [Discussion on Apple Support Forums](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/6844365?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: I have the same problem and, like in your case, my fake word does not appear in  ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary. So how can I remove it from that file if it is not there, as your suggested?