# Where is the spelling exception list that TeXShop uses?

Tags: texshop, filesystem-access

Does someone know where this file is on a Mac? I would like to access this file in order to make a copy of it, just in case TeXShop looses it...

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough. Does anyone know where the dictionary list of words is stored on a Mac for TeXShop ?

Comment: I found the answer. Its controlled through MacOS : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285777/location-of-spelling-dictionary-in-texshop-on-el-capitan